# OpenShift deploy an application from private registry by using "oc new pp" command

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

In `OpenShift`, I want to deploy application by using **docker image** which its location is on the private docker registry. To do this I have written the following command from terminal by using **OpenShift Container Platform Command Line Interface (oc CLI)**

```
oc new-app --docker-image=myregistry.com/mycompany/myimage  --name=private --insecure-registry=true
```

I received an error which type is **407 proxy authentication** when I run the above command. Because, To pull the image from my private registry need to authentication. I have a secret for this authentication, too, **but I don't know how can add the secret to above command.**

Could you help me, please? or another way ...

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I could have solved. The problem is lack of steps while creating **secret** for private docker registry. The all steps are:

1) If you do not already have a Docker credentials file for the secured registry, you can create a secret by running:

```
$ oc create secret docker-registry <pull_secret_name> \
    --docker-server=<registry_server> \
    --docker-username=<user_name> \
    --docker-password=<password> \
    --docker-email=<email>
```

2) To use a secret for pulling images for Pods, you must add the secret to your service account:

```
$ oc secrets link default <pull_secret_name> --for=pull
```

3) To use a secret for pushing and pulling build images, the secret must be mountable inside of a Pod. You can do this by running:

```
$ oc secrets link builder <pull_secret_name>
```

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/openshift_images/managing-images/using-image-pull-secrets.html